# What is the difference between these two burden resistor configuration

Tags: resistors

On my ADC evaluation board the burden resistor configuration used is like on the left side , but from what I know this configuration is for non differential signals, This ADC ***ALWAYS*** takes differential measurement and cannot extrapolate the reading on P or N line separately. The way I have always seen others do it like in current transformer is the configuration on the right side.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ4saKm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is there any benefits why i would choose to configure it like the left side ?

Answer (score 1):

"the ADC ALWAYS takes differential measurement" that's not true, it's valid only for differential type ADC.

Every signal has to have a reference voltage, usually the GND. Left wiring type should be used where possible (differential ADC), and the right wiring, when you have a single ended ADC, probably you need also to buffer and bias the signal in case the signal comes from current transformer.

Comment: I apologize if i was not so clear but what i ment was the ADC of the evaluation board always take differential measurement because it is as you said a differential type adc

Comment: What would be the possible problems if i wont tie the left type to ground?

Comment: @Jakequin then you have a floating input, you can even destroy the input due to over voltage. Which specific device are you referring at? Must be some power meter?

Comment: The [ADC](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads131m08.pdf?ts=1610233499066&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FADS131M08) does recommend using the configuration on the right. But CT such as [this](https://sc01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1wqoRGXXXXXXdXFXXq6xXFXXXh/200286647/HTB1wqoRGXXXXXXdXFXXq6xXFXXXh.jpg_.webp) have burden resistor like on the right built in to them

Comment: Take a claasic CT or the one who has only the protection diode, without the burden resistor. You may have to choose the correct burden resistor to meet your requirement, not just a whichever resistor they provide.